# Linked Server OLE DB MSOLAP Provider Very Slow for Large DataSets

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I have a SQL Server (RSQL) and a SSAS Server (RSSAS). RSQL has a linked server to RSSAS, naming [LinkedCube]

[Here is a screenshot of my Linked Server Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka4Vw.png)

I use SSMS to connect to RSQL and then run a query that returns data from SSAS using linked server. The result set contains 100,000 rows and it took 17 seconds to return data completely.

The Profiler said that MDX query duration is about 3 seconds, so it took 14 seconds to return data.

The network connection has a maximum transfer rate at 100MB/sec, so 14 seconds is not acceptable.

Do you know why it took to much time to transfer data ?

In my opinion, I think that there are problems with OLE DB for MOLAP. I use **format=Tabular** in connection string, default SSAS format may be **format=Native** , so it need more time to transform data format. If I use Excel to get the same data from SSAS, it is faster, 5 seconds in total. Excel use ADOMD.NET instead of OLE DB Provider and Excel request data using  **Native** format.

```
EXEC('SELECT {[Measures].[Qty]} ON COLUMNS,{[Product].Members} ON ROWS FROM [AnalysisServicesCube]')AT [LinkedCube]
```

Comment: Have you tried using SQL Server Integration services for this purpose.
Then you avoid using a linked server.

Comment: Thanks but my purpose is to write a stored procedure in T-SQL to get large data from SSAS to improve performance, not just import/export data as SSIS does.